# List of all sub documents in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Strangely I couldn't find the answer to that very simple question and I can't find a way to do it by myself with the doc.

This is an example schema

```
{
    Test : [
        {
           foo:0,fighter:[]
        },
        {
           foo:1,fighter:[]
        },
        {
           food:2,fighter:[]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to retrieve all the documents in `Test`

I've found that to retrieve the content of the first `fighter` you can just do :

`Collection.find({_id: 0 , 'Test.foo': 0})`

But what about getting the whole `Test` array ? or the whole `fighter` array ?

```
{ foo: 0, fighter: [ "john", "fitz", "gerald" ] }
{ foo: 1, fighter: [] } 
{ food: 2, fighter: [] }
```

or just the whole `figther` ( foo 0 ) content

```
"john", "fitz", "gerald"
```

The only thing I've found would be `Collection.findOne({_id: id}).Test` , but it's not working , I'm getting

> undefined " Test" method.

Comment: "i'm getting undefined " Test" method" - this means that there's not such document by that id.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use projection for that. You can do something like this :

`Collection.find({_id: 0}, { Test: { $elemMatch: { foo : 0 } } } )`

This will give you the `Test` array, but with just one element, i.e. the first element that matches the criteria `foo : 1`

To get only the `Test` array and not the whole document use this :

`Collection.find({_id: 0}, { Test: 1, _id: 0 } )`

Also

You can find more about this [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#examples)

Hope this helps.